# How do I set up a delay within a command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to recreate Runner in Minecraft 1.9 singleplayer, but I cannot get how to set up a delay so that the player can run without getting killed.

Comment: What do you mean by "a delay within a command block"?

Comment: `so that the player can run without getting killed.`, I think u don't mean it like that, right? You wan't the player having to run, for not getting killed. Please fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Add an scoreboard objective:
`/scoreboard objectives add Moving stat.walkOneCm`

Run the following commands in a clock(in exactly that order):

```
/kill @a[score_Moving=0,m=!1]
/scoreboard players set @a Moving 0
```

**Warning:**
Be careful when setting this up.
You will get killed, when not walking/running.
And when the machine is killing you the whole time, you have no chance to disable it(except for external tools).

Comment: You could change that to ```/kill @a[score_Moving=0,m=!1]```  so it only kills you, if you are not in creative mode.

Comment: @Lars Thanks for the suggestion, I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Jumping will kill you in this setup, as stat.walkOneCm does *not* increase when jumping.

Comment: Whoops. I accidentally approved and realised that the edit was a 'hijack'.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a "grace period" for not running? I.e. the command blocks kill you if you stand still for more than, say, a second?

If so, you can run these in a repeat/chain setup:

```
/scoreboard players set @a OnGround 0 {OnGround:0b}
/scoreboard players set @a OnGround 1 {OnGround:1b}
/scoreboard players remove @a[score_Moving_min=1] Moving 1
/scoreboard players set @a[score_Moving_min=20] Moving 20
/kill @a[score_Moving=0,score_OnGround_min=1,tag=Running]
/scoreboard players tag @a[score_Moving=0,score_OnGround_min=1,tag=Running] remove Running
```

`Moving` is a `stat.walkOneCm` type objective, the `OnGround` tag is `dummy`. Moving does not increase while jumping/falling, which makes this addition necessary or else jumping or falling could kill you. The `Running` tag is to prevent an endless kill loop, add it to anyone that has to run to not die.

To adjust the timing, adjust the score set in the second command (both in the target selector and the set command) to the number of ticks the player may stand still (20 ticks = 1 second). This command acts like a "hard cap" on the Moving score (it can never exceed the value given).

Comment: You should mention, that the "tag" commands are only available in the latest 1.9 Snapshots, as the full 1.9 version isn't available yet.

Comment: Milesman32 uses 1.9(snapshots), but other people with a similar problem, may use an earlier version.